# What is the meaning of the character "$\,\mathscr{C}\,$"?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

[image: pic]
The character in the circle with question mark.
Is it mean Lebesgue?
Thx for reply! :)

Comment: This is the letter 'C': $\mathscr C$.

Comment: Maybe "complement". I think it would make sense to show more from this text. Maybe someone can deduce the meaning of the symbol from the content of this paragraph. And it may be useful , too , if you post the source of the text.

Answer (score 1):

It's a capital C, in a certain font. The TeX command to write it is `\mathscr C`: $\mathscr C$. As to what it means, the book ought to have told you. It is not a conventional, well-known notation that I'm aware of.

Comment: Thanks you for replying

Comment: It’s either closure or complement.  Look it up in the book.